# Drupal exposed view

Tags: php, drupal, view, drupal-exposed-filter

is there a way to not display any results initially until the form has been submitted?

Also, I cant see where I can override the exposed form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@googletorp mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421635/drupal-exposed-view/3421753#3421753), you can override the expose form using [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter): check out a couple examples in other questions to get an idea of how it works:

- [remove a logic operator(unlocked) of a exposed filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419639/remove-a-logic-operatorunlocked-of-a-exposed-filter/3419919#3419919)
- [Supplying a predefined list of options for an exposed item in a view in Drupal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397655/supplying-a-predefined-list-of-options-for-an-exposed-item-in-a-view-in-drupal/3399017#3399017)

To display a blank form unless the user fills out the exposed form, you can use [`hook_views_query_alter()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/function/hook_views_query_alter/6) in a custom module:

```
function test_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  $filter_set = FALSE;

  foreach ($view->filter as $filter) {
    // Check if we've found a filter identifier that is set
    if ($filter->options['exposed'] && array_key_exists($filter->options['expose']['identifier'], $_GET)) {
      $filter_set = TRUE;
      break;
    }
  }

  // If the filter isn't set, add a WHERE clause to the query that
  // cannot be TRUE. This ensures the view returns no results.
  if (!$filter_set) {
    $query->add_where(0, 'FALSE');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, I had to adjust this a bit because the view had multiple filters and it was adding the query on the first filter and so affecting the following exposed filter. But, I got it working, cheers.. Also, a couple other things, the second part of my question, how can I theme the exposed form? And, how can I display a message for no results found?

Comment: Further to this Mark, I would like to be able to combine the exposed search field to search multiple database fields, its currently exposing 'title' but I would like say 'description' and 'address', but with just a single search field.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the form with `hook_form_alter` in a custom module.

I don't believe there is a option in the Views UI to display nothing before selection. In your theme you could check if there is an selection, and hide the results if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a default filter (between the exposed ones) with a comparison that is always false.

Answer (score 0):

If a filter is made optional in the exposed filter settings, the view should still display the results...

Answer (score 0):

In `Exposed Form Section` change the `Exposed` form style from `basic` to `input required`